# Why doesn't MigLayout stretch the size of this table cell to fit the grid?

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

Below is a screenshot of a GUI I created with Java Swing and MigLayout as the main layout manager. "Game Board" has kept its smallest possible size, but this is not desired behavior. I'd want this `JPanel` to stretch all the way to the right and bottom.

Why isn't the layout behaving as I expect it? Can I change this behavior?

[image: GUI]

Here's the relevant code from the main window:

```
_frame.setLayout(new MigLayout());
_frame.getContentPane().add(_board);
_frame.getContentPane().add(_cardPick, "wrap, span 2 1");
_frame.getContentPane().add(_regList);
_frame.getContentPane().add(_chkPowerdown, "gapleft 15, align left bottom");
_frame.getContentPane().add(_btnSubmit, "gapleft 15, wrap, align left bottom");
_frame.pack();
```

The first three components all have a `TitledBorder`. They're custom-made `JPanel`s with a `MigLayout`.

Comment: OK, let me spare some typing for others: where's the code?

Comment: agreed with Marko, .....

Comment: many possible reasons - you could try tinkering with layout col/row constraints (something like [max][min],[max][min] assumming im looking at a 2x2 master layout ...) but, like stated, seeing code will help.

Comment: Sorry about that, folks. I thought this might have been default behavior or something. I added layout constructing code snippet above. If there's anything else that might be relevant, let me know.

Comment: But there's no layout hint on the board component. The default is not to stretch. Have you read about `grow` and `fill` constraints?

Comment: I passed `grow` as an argument to the board adding command and it looks fine now. If you post this as an answer, I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469289/why-doesnt-miglayout-stretch-the-size-of-this-table-cell-to-fit-the-grid#comment13524792_10469289) from Marko Topolnik fixed my problem:

> But there's no layout hint on the board component. The default is not to stretch. Have you read about `grow` and `fill` constraints?